# Is there anyway to use StartAt with Firestore queries if you don't have a document reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a list with pagination using data coming from the firestore.

I have read the docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors and it's stated that if you want to use the pagination you should use `startAt` with a document reference.

However, my list as objects it's not using document references, because my data are not firestore documents They are processed as in most apps and all db metadata are stripped out. Such as the document references.

So in order to find the last object in my list I need todo a `get` call to the firestore to get the document reference.

Is there any other way I can use `startAt` without having to pull (get) a complete document from the firestore , since I do have the ID of the referenced doc I need?

PS. I would not like to store any DB(firestore) data on my objects/classes. They are not tight coupled to the DB as they shouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `startAt`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#startAt) says:

> #### startAt
>
> `startAt(snapshotOrVarArgs) returns firebase.firestore.Query`
>
> Creates a new query where the results start at the provided document (inclusive). The starting position is relative to the order of the query. The document must contain all of the fields provided in the `orderBy` of the query.
>
> Parameter
>
> `snapshotOrVarArgs` (non-null `firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot` or repeatable any type)
>
> The snapshot of the document you want the query to start at **or the field values to start this query at, in order of the query's order by**.

So you can either pass in a `DocumentSnapshot` or a value for each field that you're filtering/ordering on. Just having the document ID is not enough, unless your query is only filtered/ordered by document ID.

Comment: As always thank you. BTW what is `or the field values to start this query at, in order of the query's order by.` not in the docs?

Comment: I copied that from the docs. It means that you must specify the field values to `startAt` (or any of the offset methods) in the same order that you specify your order/filter parameters in.

Comment: Ok maybe my mistake but I am looking at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors  and there I cannot find this info. 
Also Angular Fire only accepts a docRef on their docs and tested